# Panorama decompression is taking too long in Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, compression, lzma

I have a scene with a few panoramic images.. trouble is that they each weigh a lot. On disk between 400kB ~ 1MB, on RAM load it weighs around 30MB, and after applying `Texture2D.Compress()` it weighs around 3MB ~ 4MB.

This scene needs to run with Unity WebGL, and for that reason it needs to take up as little memory as possible. When i run the conpression function on the image, it freezes the scene and causes very bad user experience...

I tried to find a workaround with LZMA compression but it's being too slow. Are there any other compression algorithms I can use within Unity C# environment, or any alternatives to `Compress()` that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Memory usage only applies to the decompressed texture. You need to decompress it and load it into memory to _show_ it. I don't see any use in compressing it during the program run.

Comment: One very simple way of reducing the final uncompressed size is probably just to, y'know... scale down the image.